# hibernate on client swing application running instances on LAN

Tags: java, hibernate, rmi

I have written 2 parts of my program - client & server.

Server is installed on the machine where my database is (mysql).

Client is then installed on various machines and then the client interacts with the server 
using RMI.

Server is using hibernate to work with the database (mysql).

Now if the clients try to enter a new row in the database at the same time, all of them gets to have the same fields which were to be incremented by some logic written on the server side.

At my part I have already tried making the methods synchronized but it doesn't seem to work. It appears as if multiple clients are making the same method  call simultaneously.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem? I think hibernate can process simultaneous call of methods

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak The problem is that those methods (on the server remote class) are using hibernate to insert data into database. And in those methods some calculation is done to fill data in X field. If I try making these calls in sequence I have no issue, but when I try simultaneously those intend to save the same data in the table.

Comment: may be try to use concurrency locks

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak thanks for your reply. But how do I proceed for it ? Have you got any links for that ?

Comment: look at this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html

Comment: thanks, I was thinking you were talking about hibernate concurrency locks.